Is there an entanglement distillation algorithm that works for arbitrary two-qubit pure states?
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}$
Consider a pure state of the form
$$
\ket{\psi} = \bigotimes_{n=1}^\infty \ket{\phi},
$$
where $ \ket{\phi} \in \mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B $ is an entangled two-qubit state ($\ket{\phi}$ is the same for each $n$). Is there a non-adapative entanglement distillation protocol, using only local operations and classical communication (LOCC), that with probability one can asymptotically distill this state into a tensor product of infinitely many copies of some maximally entangled pair, without requiring prior knowledge of the initial state? In other words, does there exist a non-adapative protocol that works universally for any such initial state $ \ket{\psi} $? If not, is there anything that prevents the existence of such a protocol?

I doubt that such a protocol exists, but a proof doesn’t immediately come to mind. Assuming the existence of quantum-secure one way functions, such a protocol is unlikely to be efficient (even with knowledge of the entangled state) https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.02783

If you had knowledge of the entangled state, then couldn't you just perform some standard entanglement distillation protocol? Is there a reason that wouldn't be efficient?

Here is a construction from the linked paper: Suppose that f is a quantum secure one-way function (i.e. difficult to invert). Then, consider the state held between $AB$: $\sum_x |x\rangle_A |f(x)\rangle_B$. Then a distillation scheme would need to invert the one-way function in order to transform this state into standard Bell states

Sorry for not making it clear in my original post, but what I had in mind is that the entangled state is the same for each $n$.

I'm not sure I'm understanding the question correctly. The state $\vert\psi\rangle$ is written as an infinite tensor product, so are we to assume that Alice and Bob each have infinitely many qubits? One must be careful when formalizing this sort of scenario and what sorts of protocols are permitted — but if this is the assumption, then it seems to me that Alice and Bob could sacrifice every other qubit for the sake of tomography, learn what the state is, and then distill the remaining copies (of which there would still be infinitely many) with a standard protocol.

Yes, we are to assume that Alice and Bob each have infinitely many qubits. The protocol that you have stated definitely works, but I guess the question I had in mind is "Is there a non-adaptive algorithm to accomplish this task?". I will edit the question to make this more clear. Sorry for not being more precise in the original question.

You have to be quite careful about what the infinite tensor product means here. If you simply mean n copies, with n approaching infinity, its very different from actually n=infinity. The space that your state lives on as written is very large (more than uncountable) and would not be a Hilbert space
